# How do I get mutilple lines to a single variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

Below are my cases in Perl programming:

## CASE-1

```
print "User input :\n";

my $test = <>;

print "\nTest1:\n $test";
```

## CASE-2

```
my $test2="hello

how are you";

print "\nTest2:$test2";
```

In case-1 I'm passing the output as below:

```
hello

how are you
```

but it is considering only hello (first line)

In case-2 I'm assigning to a variable test2.

it is considering both the lines.

Can someone please help me to read the both lines to a single variable from user input?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `$/` which is a special variable to tell perl not to stop capturing input when a newline is encountered.

However once you set this and if you're capturing from STDIN then pressing enter to end the input will no longer work - instead you need to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on posix or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> on windows to end the input.

Heres an example:

```
use Modern::Perl;

local $/ = undef;
my $value = <>;    # enter multiline string end with Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z

print "VALUE = $value";
```

Finally if you are using `$/` in functions it's important to use the `local` keyword. This means that `$/` will only be set inside the scope of your function and won't affect other captures.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Is it possible to enter some other characters like "EOL" or "END"...... instead of pressing ctr+d or ctrl+z

Comment: Is it possible to enter some other characters like "EOL" or "END"...... instead of pressing ctr+d or ctrl+z

Comment: You could set `$/` to "END\n" which should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If - as mentioned in comments - you're looking for a separate 'end of line' marker you can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $input; 
while (my $line = <>) {
    last if $line =~ m/^END$/;    
    $input .= $line; 
}

print $input;
```

This reads one line at a time still, but checks each as it goes for a pattern (in this case just the word 'END'). If the line doesn't match, it concatenates it onto `$input`.

Alternatively:

```
local $/ = "END\n"; 
my $stuff = <>; 
print $stuff;
```